# Alternative JAVA WAR/ZIP/JAR reader/manipulator library

Tags: java, file, jar, zip, war

I am struggling to find some alternative library which would make browsing some.war file.

Problem is I need to parse WAR file then find specific JAR by name and some of the contents inside JAR file. Then I must parse those contents e.g. pom.xml from those jars to create a separate maven project module with only certain dependencies and configuration appended from other resources. I found **java.util.zip** package a bit inconvenient and cluttering.

Is there some alternative to **java.util.zip** that could make parsing/reading war without such headaches like switching between ZipFile/ZipEntry -> JarFile/JarEntry ? Something that could treat zip/war/jar and jar files inside war archive just like a directory ? Or one must craft his/her own solution ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I used [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) for similar task: if you wrap one `ZipInputStream` into another one, you can transparently access the archive inside the another archive without unpacking the top-level one. Here's short sample showing how to use it:

```
public class ZipTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]))
        {
            listZipEntries(1, is);
        }
    }

    private static void listZipEntries(int indent, InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is);
        while(true) {
            ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry();
            if(entry == null)
                return;
            System.out.printf("%"+indent+"s%s\n", "", entry.getName());
            if(entry.getName().endsWith(".zip") || entry.getName().endsWith(".jar"))
                listZipEntries(indent+3, zip);
        }
    }
}
```

It dumps names of the files inside zip-archive. If it encounters file which name ends with `.zip` or `.jar`, it goes inside and dumps it recursively. For me it looks quite simple and no third-party code is necessary.